# Why am I getting "double free or corruption" with the following code?

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a simple program to make sure I fully understand how pointers in C work as I go through Harvard's CS50. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = 5;
    printf("the address of pointer a is: %p\n", &a);
    printf("the address that a is pointing to is: %p\n", a);
    printf("the contents of a are: %i\n", *a);

    printf("please enter a new value for a: \n");
    scanf("%i", a);
    printf("the address of pointer a is: %p\n", &a);
    printf("the address that a is pointing to is: %p\n", a);
    printf("the contents of a are: %i\n", *a);

    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 7;
    printf("the address of pointer b is: %p\n", &b);
    printf("the address that b is pointing to is: %p\n", b);
    printf("the contents of b are: %i\n", *b);

    a = b;
    printf("setting a = b\n");
    printf("the address of pointer a is: %p\n", &a);
    printf("the address that a is pointing to is: %p\n", a);
    printf("the contents of a are: %i\n", *a);

    free(a);
    free(b);
}
```

It compiles w/o issues, but when executed, I get the following error: "*** Error in `./address': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000018b7030 ***
Aborted"

This problem goes away if I get rid of either the free(a) or free(b) statements, however valgrind reveals a memory leak:
"==9626== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9626==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9626==    by 0x4206AD: main (address.c:6)"

I've looked through the other questions here and other websites that mention double free corruption, but still can't figure out quite what the issue is... I have a feeling that the answer is simple, and the issue probably lies in the statement "a = b", however I don't really get why I wouldn't be able to have one pointer point to a memory location that another one is pointing to, and then free the memory taken by both pointers...

Comment: Maybe instead of the assignment `a = b;` you meant `*a = *b;` — these do very different things, and the second notation (with the `*`'s) won't cause a problem.  It assigns the value that `b` points at to the memory that `a` points at.

Comment: regarding: `It compiles w/o issues`  This is not true. When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu17` )  Note, other compilers have different options to perform the same functionality.

Comment: does it cleanly compile? No.  The compiler outputs warnings for 2 out of every 3 calls to `printf()`  This (probably) will not stop the code from working, but it sure isn't code with no problems

Comment: OT:  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: You are NOT freeing memory "taken by pointers". You are freeing memory *pointed by* pointers. Since two pointers point to the same memory, you naturally end up with double free.

Comment: Awesome, thank you guys, this is a lot clearer now! @user3629249 I'm yet to learn how to use gcc properly since the CS50 class uses a "make" function created by the professor/staff for compiling. With the parameters you suggested, I get "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=gnu17’", but when I remove that one, I can see the warnings you mentioned. It'll take me some time to dig through those!

Comment: suggest changing: `-std=gnu17` to `-std=gnu11` as the C17 standard is not available everywhere (yet)

Comment: here is a (somewhat dated) link to the `gcc` command line options and what they do.  [gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
 a = b; // a now points to the same thing as b does

...

free(a);
free(b);
```

... which is semantically equivalent to

```
free(b);
free(b);
```

That's the double free - b gets free'd twice - and that is disallowed in C.

---

For your memory leaking problem:

When you're setting `a = b` you're losing the original value of `a`. `a` was a pointer to the memory that you allocated with `int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));` that is now lost. You need to save that address and pass it to `free()` before exit, if you want valgrind to stop complaining about leaks.

For each address that `malloc()` returns (except zero... ^_^), you should call `free()` with that very same address as argument.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! Creating a temporary variable for storing the original value of a and then freeing that fixes the memory leak.

Comment: @Matvey my pleasure :) Feel free to accept my answer if you want to give me some credit

Answer (score 4):

Let's reduce your code to the bare minimum:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));

    a = b; // after the assignment the pointer value previously held by a is gone.
           // both pointers point to the same memory. The memory previously pointed
           // to by a can no longer be free()d since its address is gone.

    free(a); // free the memory pointed to by b (a is a copy of b) once
    free(b); // free the memory pointed to by b twice --> boom.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
 a = b;
```

You are effectively making `a` and `b` point to the same address (a.k.a. be the same pointer). So this is what causes the error:

```
free(a); // Frees the location where b points to
free(b);
```